# SymmetricSecurityKey in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net, jwt

I'm trying to create Asp.NET Core API and add Jwt authentication.
In all examples, that I've found so far is used SymmetricSecurityKey.
I've added Aspnetcore.Authentication.JwtBearer package but there is doesn't exist SymmetricSecurityKey. 
What package I've to add to resolve dependency to this class?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 16):

For me it required `using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;`

Answer (score 5):

Problem was solved by adding aspnetcore.identity package.

Answer (score 5):

**For .NET Core 3.0:**

A lot of things have been broken off into individual packages that have to be added to your project.  Therefore:

```cs
$ dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer --version 3.0.0
```

Which adds the following line to the .csproj:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0" />
```

At that point, [as other answers have stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44668555/3443552), you can import:

```cs
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
```

[Nuget Package Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer)